# DbContext/ObjectDataSource Update Issue

Tags: entity-framework-4, objectdatasource, dbcontext

I have a `ObjectDataSource` Which Calls business layer methods to update EF and save. I have this weird problem. Following is ODS markup:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsDeviceForm" runat="server"  ypeName="Spectre.BLL..DeviceManager"
  DataObjectTypeName="Model.Device" SelectMethod="GetById" 
  InsertMethod="Insert" oninserting="OnItemInserting" UpdateMethod="UpdateEx" 
  oninserted="OnItemInserted" onupdated="OnItemUpdated" 
  onupdating="OnItemUpdating" onobjectcreated="OnOdsObjectCreated" 
  onselected="OnOdsItemSelected"  ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" OldValuesParameterFormatString="orig{0}"   >
  <SelectParameters>
    <asp:SessionParameter Name="primaryKey" SessionField="SelectedDeviceId" Type="Int32" />
  </SelectParameters>
```

Following is BLL and repositoryCode:
BLL:

```
public void UpdateEx(T entity, T origentity)
{
  try
  {
    repository.Update(origentity, entity);
    repository.Save();
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
    throw;
  }
}
```

Repository:

```
public void Update(T orig, T newEntity)
{
  myContext.Entry<T>(newEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(newEntity);

}
```

When This code runs I get an exception:

> Member 'CurrentValues' cannot be called for the entity of type
>   'Device' because the entity does not exist in the context. To add an
>   entity to the context call the Add or Attach method of DbSet.

But if I do dbset.attach then I get exception that the entity already exists.

I have no idea what can I do, seems like a circular problem to me. I have gone half bald pulling my hair over this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You may have created new instances for the navigational properties in your device class which are already loaded to the context. Eg

```
device.Foo = new Foo { Id = 1 };
context.Devices.Attach(device);
```

The context may already has a `Foo` instance with `Id=1`. So when you attach `Device` it tries to attach the `Foo` also but fails because there is a matching instance which is already tracked by the context.

If possible try setting the scalar properties only.

```
device.FooId = 1;
context.Devices.Attach(device);
```

To determine whether `Foo` instance is loaded

```
var foo = context.ObjectStateManager
  .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EtityState.Modified | EntityState.Unchanged)
  .Select(s => s.Entity).OfType<Foo>().SingleOrDefault(f => f.Id == device.FooId);

if (foo != null)
{
   // foo is loaded
}
```

Or check whether context has loaded the navigational property and if so use that instance.

Comment: How do I check if has loaded it?